# The hardness of solving $x^2=2$

Tags: time-complexity

What's the hardness of the following problem: $\textbf{argmin}_x\{|x^2-2|\}$.

By analytical calculation, I know the solution is $\pm \sqrt{2}$. But I am quite confused about whether it is hard with regarding to  its computation complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the hardness of the following problem: $\textbf{argmin}_x\{|x^2-2|\}$.

It is $O(1)$. There is a single answer: $x = \sqrt{2}$. That means that, regardless of how that answer is represented, a computer can just output the answer and it solves your problem.

In general, to consider the *hardness* or *complexity* of a problem, you need there to be at least one variable as input; in particular, you need **infinitely many possible input values.** Otherwise, every problem can be solved trivially by just outputting the answer.